# Spacing between sections in a form

Tags: swift, swiftui

Is it possible to adjust the spacing between section blocks in a form? Ive tried using .padding() but it only moves whatever is inside the section, not the actual section itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try a spacer between the sections:

```
Spacer(minLength: CGFloat?)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this property without giving float value too

```
    Spacer() // this will work
```